# Property of little o

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Assuming that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)^n$ exists and is finite, is it true that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(f(n) - o(n))^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)^n$$

If not, are there any conditions that can be assumed such that this would be true?

For context, I am trying to prove that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n} - f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n = e^{-\lambda t}$$

where $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}{h} = 0$$

Comment: It's not even true that $\lim (f(n) + o(1))^n = \lim f(n)^n$ all the time: $\lim (1 + 1/n)^n = e \not= 1$. I suspect you meant $o(1)$, not $o(n)$, since why would you think $o(n)$ terms should be negligible in the limit?

Comment: @KCd I believe the $o(n)$ terms are negligible compared to $f(n)$. I am not exactly sure though.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Let $f(n) = 0$ and the $o(n)$ term be $\sqrt{n}$. Then $(f(n) - o(n))^n = \sqrt{n}^n = n^{n/2}$, which doesn't have limit $0$ as $n \to \infty$ like $f(n)^n$ does.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your actual goal, you not assign a value to $f(0)$.  We can set $f(0) = 0$ without affecting the property that $f(x) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$ (I suspect that might be what you really want, and not $f(x) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0$).

Anyway, your goal is clear if $t = 0$, so let $t \not= 0$.  Since you implicitly want $\lambda$ and $t$ to be constant, for $t \not= 0$ let $g(x) = -f(tx)$. Then $g(x) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$, so your task is equivalent to showing
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - \lambda t/n + g(1/n))^n = e^{-\lambda t}.
$$
If $\lambda = 0$, this becomes $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + g(1/n))^n = 1$. To verify this, it suffices to take logarithms of both sides (a continuous function) and show $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\log(1 + g(1/n)) = 0$.

As $x \to 0$, $\log(1 + x) = O(x)$, so as $n \to \infty$, $n\log(1 + g(1/n)) = O(ng(1/n))$. We have $ng(1/n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $g(x) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\log(1 + g(1/n)) = 0$. Now exponentiate both sides of that to see $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + g(1/n))^n = 1$.

If $\lambda \not= 0$, then set $u = -\lambda t$ and your limit is equivalent to showing
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + u/n + g(1/n))^n = e^u
$$
when $g(x) = o(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$.  Take logarithms of both sides and use he estimate $\log(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$.

Since
$$
1 + \frac{u}{n} + g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{n}\left(u + \frac{g(1/n)}{1/n}\right), 
$$
your task can be expressed as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{u + \varepsilon(n)}{n}\right)^n = e^u
$$
where $u$ is constant and $\varepsilon(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. The minus signs, $\lambda$, and $t$ in your formulation of the problem are distractions even if they were present in the original setting.

Answer (score 0):

Notation used are a little bit confusing,  I'm assuming that with this

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(f^*(n) - o(n))^n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f^*(n)^n$$

we are assuming $f^*(n)=1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n}$ and $o(n) = f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)$, and then it is easy to see that

$$\left(1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n} - f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n =\left[\left(1 - \lambda\frac{t}{n} - f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^{\frac1{- \lambda\frac{t}{n} - f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)}}\right]^{t\cdot \frac{- \lambda\frac{t}{n} - f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)}{\frac t n}} \to e^{-\lambda t}$$

under the condition that $\frac{f\left(\frac t n\right)}{\frac t n} \to 0$.